# Limiting the number of linesin a HTML "Label" tag

Tags: html, jsp, label

i have a html label within a jsp page. Text for that particular label is printed dynamically. I want to limit the number of lines that can be printed to 2, and the rest of the string should be cut off. Is there a attribute or anyother way to do this. I have mentioned the label below.

```
    <label style="top:202px; left:50px;position:absolute; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:0.9em; font-weight:bold; color:#000000; max-width: 400px; word-wrap: break-word; line-height: 11px"><s:property value="getRequest().get('name')"/></label>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A label doesn't have a `maxlength` property.

I guess from your code `<s:property value="getRequest().get('name')"/>` you are using Struts tag to render the label value.
Then in action class

```
String labelName = "abcdefghijk.........";  //label variable 
.....
....
//check the length of labelName is not greater than 200 characters
//e.g. consider 200 characters you need to test how many characters fit in 2 lines
// limit to those number of characters then
if(labelName.length() >= 201)
   lableName = labelName.substring(0,200);
```